# MEAN stack add new module

Tags: mean-stack, mean.io

I created new module with name "mean.recipes". But it's javascript files are not loaded.

I am missing injection of dependency to load those modules but not able to find the place.

I went through javascript files but could not find the exact file.

can someone point me to right file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the documentation helps.. If it's MEAN.io you can find more information here: http://learn.mean.io/#mean-stack-packages-dependency-injection